# XML with empty prefix transformation with XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I'm willing to use `XSLT` to transform XML files to other XML files by removing (`TextLine`) elements. However, the elements are not removed as I expect in the output XML files. I imagine that I'll have to modify the XSLT file, but I don't know how. Let me know what should be done.

*I suspect that the root cause of the issue is that elements in the XML files have an empty prefix namespace.*

The details are the following ones.

An XML `test-01.xml` file that contains empty prefix namespace elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4#"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/v4/alto-4-2.xsd">
    <TextLine TAGREFS="LT9"/>
    <TextLine TAGREFS="LT10"/>
    <TextLine TAGREFS="LT9"/>
    <TextLine TAGREFS="LT8"/>
</alto>
```

And I'm using the following `date.xslt` file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TextLine"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Note: I'm using python `lxml` to perform the transformation. However, this shouldn't have any influence on the process as I could use any other XML transformer as `xsltproc`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your assumption that that the default namespace was the cause of your XSLT not functioning as desired was correct. Try this XSLT-1.0 instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:loc="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4#">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="loc:TextLine"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```